# play framework initial-data.yml parsing error

Tags: playframework

Getting below error while starting the application.

****Cannot parse the /conf/initial-data.yml file: mapping values are not allowed here****

Can anyone please tell me wht exactly this error mean ?

I am not able to rectify this error.

Comment: Can we see the content of your initial-data.yml file?

Comment: The classical error in YAML : always remember, not \t in you YAML ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file initial-data.yml has malformed YAML.
I suggest pasting the contents of the intial-data.yml here.